# Xtext: Create an EMF Resource on the fly

Tags: xtext, emf

for reasons, i need to create a non-persistent EMF resource within the Scoping. So i would like to get hold of the ResourceSet that my Language uses. But i need to get it not in the UI project but the main project.

i tried to get it in my ScopeProvider class with

```
@Inject ResourceSet
@Inject Provider<ResourceSet>
@Inject IResourceFactory
```

However, none of these ever get injected (stay null) although in the DefaultRuntimeModule, there are indeed bindings for at least ResourceSet and IResourceFactory. I use Xtext 2.5.1.

I would also accept other ways to create an EMF Resource on the fly

Regards,

clericc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
@Inject Provider<XtextResourceSet> resourceSetProvider;
```

Also don't forget to execute `<YourLanguage>StandaloneSetup.doSetup()` in your non-ui app to initialize emf registries and make all your classes injected properly.

Comment: nope sorry, this provider does not get injected either. I am running my language exclusively in an Eclipse UI, so the RuntimeModule should kick in.

Comment: @clericc, if you have UI app you should mix Runtime, UI and Shared module when creating injector, as Xtext generator does. UI module doesn't have bindings which Runtime module has. How do you create ScopeProvider? Is it initialized by proper injector?

Comment: i just discovered that i know nothing about Guice. All these methods failed because i injected the into a class member variable but wanted to use them inside the class constructor. This does not work, now i know that i can inject into the constructor. So everything's fine now. Thanks for the proposals